# Pagination For Page Post Type

Tags: pages, pagination

I try to use the Eric Meyer's pagination codes to make it working for `page` post type, but unable to figure out how to make it working. It's always show the first page.

Here is the codes:

```
<?php /* Pagination - Thanx to and (c) 2009 by Eric Martin - License: GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE */
function paginate($args = null) {
    $defaults = array( 
        'page' => null,
        'pages' => null, 
        'range' => 3,
        'gap' => 3, 'anchor' => 1,
        'before' => '<div class="paginate">', 'after' => '</div>',
        'nextpage' => __('&raquo;'), 'previouspage' => __('&laquo'),
        'echo' => 1
    );
    $r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    extract($r, EXTR_SKIP);
    if (!$page && !$pages) {
        global $wp_query;
        $page = get_query_var('paged');
        $page = !empty($page) ? intval($page) : 1;
        $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
        $pages = intval(ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $posts_per_page));
    }   

    $output = "";
    if ($pages > 1) {   
        $output .= "$before";
        $ellipsis = "<span class='gap'>...</span>";
        if ($page > 1 && !empty($previouspage)) {
            $output .= "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($page - 1) . "' class='prev' >$previouspage</a>";
        }       
        $min_links = $range * 2 + 1;
        $block_min = min($page - $range, $pages - $min_links);
        $block_high = max($page + $range, $min_links);
        $left_gap = (($block_min - $anchor - $gap) > 0) ? true : false;
        $right_gap = (($block_high + $anchor + $gap) < $pages) ? true : false;
        if ($left_gap && !$right_gap) {
            $output .= sprintf('%s%s%s', 
                paginate_loop(1, $anchor), 
                $ellipsis, 
                paginate_loop($block_min, $pages, $page)
            );
        }
        else if ($left_gap && $right_gap) {
            $output .= sprintf('%s%s%s%s%s', 
                paginate_loop(1, $anchor), 
                $ellipsis, 
                paginate_loop($block_min, $block_high, $page), 
                $ellipsis, 
                paginate_loop(($pages - $anchor + 1), $pages)
            );
        }
        else if ($right_gap && !$left_gap) {
            $output .= sprintf('%s%s%s', 
                paginate_loop(1, $block_high, $page),
                $ellipsis,
                paginate_loop(($pages - $anchor + 1), $pages)
            );
        }
        else {
            $output .= paginate_loop(1, $pages, $page);
        }
        if ($page < $pages && !empty($nextpage)) {
            $output .= "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($page + 1) . "' class='next' >$nextpage</a>";
        }
        $output .= $after;
    }
    if ($echo) {
        echo $output;
    }
    return $output;
}
function paginate_loop($start, $max, $page = 0) {
    $output = "";
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        $output .= ($page === intval($i)) 
            ? "<span class='page current'>$i</span>" 
            : "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "' class='page paginate' >$i</a>";
    }
    return $output;
}
?>
```

Could somebody give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you don't need too much like above on this

For example, a loop you use to retrieve pages,

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<!-- the loop etc.. -->
```

Then get the paginate links

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages //The custom WP_Query instance
) );
?>
```